# How to wait async call completed?

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, asynchronous

Suppose I have two events A and B.  Each of them raise a async call, say AsyncA and AsyncB.

What I want is: when A will call AsyncA only when AsyncB is completed.

Event A and B fired in order: A, then B.
I expect AsyncA is completed before AsyncB completed, but actually, most of the time, AsyncB is completed before AsyncA.

I can not put AsyncB call in AsyncA completed event. 
How to make sure AsyncB is always after AsyncA?

Comment: Could you explain why you can't put the call to AsyncB in the AsyncA completed handler?

Comment: +1 for this classic problem. I guess you have to make a room "somehow" to call AsyncB on AsyncA completed event.

Comment: Because event A and B is fired by different reason from different place.

Comment: When they are fired for different reasons, why are they fired synchronously? And why has the caller to think about the way they are handled? Isn't this the problem of the handler?

Answer (score 0):

If order is important than async method calls aren't appropriate.

Comment: You can't do sync call for SL

Comment: Can't call WCF services from SL? I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

As far as both calls are run asynchronously it is beyond your power to control their order. This is done by the scheduler.

But you can use TPL to have them both run synchronously:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew( ( ) => OnAsyncA() )
    .ContinueWith( ( t ) => OnAsyncB() );
```

Comment: That is a brute force approach, I think the problem can and should be designed around.  That is, design it so that B doesn't rely on A completing.  This may mean condensing all the code into method A

Comment: I don't know why this approach is brute force. But I agree that better design will avoid those problems.

Comment: Thanks, guys. Example: DataGrid in SL: click and double click on a row. single Click will make its async call. Double click will make its own async call. Double click always fire single click too. I have tried DispatcherTimer, but can't get my expection.

Comment: If that is the problem you should slow down the single click. Put the click into a queue and only if with a time threshold no more click is recognized the single click is method is executed, otherwise, if one more click was recognized, the double click method is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't guarantee completion order of the asychronous calls, but you can execute the *work* you want to do in the order you want. What you need is a way to synchronize.

In `OnAsyncA` you need to:

1. Do the work you need done, and if necessary save information required for `OnAsyncB`.
2. Set a wait handle (e.g. a [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) or [AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)).

In `OnAsyncB`,

1. Save any information required (e.g. results).
2. [Spawn a threadpool thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yd16hza%28v=VS.95%29.aspx). (Waiting the signal in the handler would be a bad idea since the WCF callback occurs on the UI thread).

In the threadpool thread,

1. Wait on the handle.
2. Do the work you normally would have done for `OnAsyncB`.

There are other variations on this, such as having a longer running thread dequeueing from a "dependent events" queue, using TPL, and such.

Remember to synchronize back to the UI thread from the threadpool thread.